# Spark application with Hive Warehouse Connector saves array and map fields wrongly in Hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using `Spark 2.4` with `Hive Warehouse Connector` and `Scala 2.11`. The current Hive Warehouse Connector provided by Hortonworks is not compatible with Spark 2.4. So I compile my jar file from https://github.com/abh1sh2k/spark-llap/pull/1/files which makes it compatible with Spark 2.4.

My Spark application reads from Kafka input stream and writes to Hive table (ORC format) using Hive output stream provided by Hive Warehouse Connector.

Here's my Spark code (Scala):

```
package example

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import za.co.absa.abris.avro.read.confluent.SchemaManager
import za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_confluent_avro

object NormalizedEventsToHive extends Logging {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("NormalizedEventsToHive")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val schema_registry_config = Map(
      "schema.registry.url"           -> "http://schema-registry:8081",
      "value.schema.naming.strategy"  -> "topic.name",
      "schema.registry.topic"         -> "events-v1",
      "value.schema.id"               -> "latest"
    )

    val input_stream_df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("subscribe", "events-v1")
      .load()

    val data = input_stream_df
      .select(from_confluent_avro(col("value"), schema_registry_config) as 'data)
      .select("data.*")

    val output_stream_df = data.writeStream.format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.streaming.HiveStreamingDataSource")
      .option("database", "default")
      .option("table", "events")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "file:///checkpoint2")
      .option("metastoreUri", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083")
      .start()

    output_stream_df.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

The input `Kafka messages` are `AVRO encoded` and `Confluent Schema Registry` is used for schema version control. `za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_confluent_avro` is used to decode the AVRO encoded Kafka messages.

Here's the AVRO schema:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "events",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id",                 "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null },
        .....
        { "name": "field_map",          "type": ["null", { "type": "map", "values": ["null", "string"] }], "default": null },
        { "name": "field_array",        "type": ["null", { "type": "array", "items": "string" }], "default": null },
        { "name": "field_array_of_map", "type": ["null", { "type": "array", "items": { "type": "map", "values": ["null", "string"] }}], "default": null }
    ]
}
```

The `events` Hive table (ORC format) is created as:

```
CREATE TABLE `events`(
  `id`                  string,
  ......
  `field_map`           map<string,string>,
  `field_array`         array<string>,
  `field_array_of_map`  array<map<string,string>>
)
CLUSTERED BY(id) INTO 9 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

The fields with `array<string>, map<string, string>, array<map<string, string>>` types, they are saved wrongly in Hive table.

When SELECT query is issued in Beeline, they show:

```
field_map               {"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeMapData@101c5674":null}
field_array             ["org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@6b5730c2"]
field_array_of_map      [{"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@ca82f1a4":null}]
```

From https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap, it mentions `Array` type is supported, although `Map` isn't. Any idea how to save `Array` correctly? Any workaround for `Map` type?

Comment: what is the version of hive that you are using?

Comment: @lev HIve version used is `3.1.2`

Comment: can you include the avro schema? @ShuwnYuanTee

Comment: @hlagos Edited my question to include my AVRO schema, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changes found on the HWC github repository pull request worked for me in Structured Streaming.

What i did:

1. Cloned @massoudm [branch](https://github.com/mazar/spark-llap/tree/StrictJsonWriter-Support)
2. In the project root directory I ran `sbt assembly`
3. I used the new created hwc jar
4. My code:

```
data
      .writeStream
      .queryName(config("stream.name") + "_query")
      .options(hiveConfig)
      .option("writer", "json")
      .format(HiveWarehouseSession.STREAM_TO_STREAM)
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
```

5. Most important are:

```
.option("writer", "json")
.format(HiveWarehouseSession.STREAM_TO_STREAM)
```

[This](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap/issues/255) is the link to the pull request.